# Exclude post_meta from Rest API Endpoint

Tags: posts, rest-api

So I know that I can call:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(
    'https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
);
```

To get all the posts from a specific website using the Rest API Endpoint.

---

I also know that we can pass in the parameters to exclude tags and categories, such as:

`https://www.example.com/wp-json/native/v1/posts?exclude_categories=42`

Based on this: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts

---

Is there a way that I can exclude specific `post_meta` posts from showing in the Rest API?

So let that I want to do: `https://www.example.com/wp-json/native/v1/posts?exclude_postmeta_key=global` and grab all posts that don't have the `global` post_meta attached to the post.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Not a solution in code, but maybe this plugin and his code helps you - https://github.com/bueltge/wp-rest-api-filter-items

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's surely possible, but not out-of-the-box.

I.e. There's no such REST query parameter in the WordPress core, but you can add it to your REST API request, e.g. via the URL query string, and then use the [`rest_<post type>_query` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) which "*Filters `WP_Query` arguments when querying posts via the REST API*" and "*Enables adding extra arguments or setting defaults for a post collection request*".

And here's an example for the `post` post type:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'my_rest_post_query', 10, 2 );
function my_rest_post_query( array $args, WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    if ( $meta_key = $request->get_param( 'exclude_postmeta_key' ) ) {
        $args['meta_key']     = $meta_key;
        $args['meta_compare'] = 'NOT EXISTS';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

So with that, `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?exclude_postmeta_key=global` would now give you the posts that **do not have** the meta named `global`.

If you need help with WordPress meta query, see the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters). ( and/or post another question :) )